# Codestyling localization is not working for all text on website

Tags: wordpress

I have a website on which content-text is in the german, i have installed ***Codestyling localization*** plugin , problem is no all the content is translated to the germen some of the text part like validations and and text inside textbox(placeholder text) remains in english,, how can i overcome this

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your theme is translation-ready, if not, you have to switch theme or add additional php.
2. Please use `Locotranslate` instead of `Codestyling Localization`.
   -> `Codestyling Localization` hasn't been updated since 2013/2/6. Also it's officially just compatible up to Wordpress version 3.5.2.
   -> `Locotranslate` provides the same features but is compatible with version 3.9.1.